# Timer.scheduledTimer does not work in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, timer

I want to call the method `func adjustmentBestSongBpmHeartRate()`  every 1.1 second. I used Timer, but it doesn't work. I have read the document and found a lot of sample code, it still does work! Is there anything I missed?

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.adjustmentBestSongBpmHeartRate), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
timer.fire()

func adjustmentBestSongBpmHeartRate() {
    print("frr")
}
```

Comment: I don't think you need to call fire()

Comment: I changed `repeats: false` to `repeats: true`, it still doesn't work.

Comment: From where do you call it?

Comment: I also deleted `timer.fire()`, no use....

Comment: I'm calling it from `override func viewDidLoad()` method

Comment: Maybe you should try from viewDidAppear?

Comment: thank you ! It worked after I moved it to viewWillAppear

Comment: Glad for you! Don't hesitate to upvote my comment ;)

Answer (score 78):

I found that creating the timer in an OperationQueue Operation did not work.  I assume this is because there is no runloop.

Therefore, the following code fixed my problem:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // timer needs a runloop?
    self.timeoutTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: self.timeout, target: self, selector: #selector(self.onTimeout(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
```

Comment: My case.. Seems obvious now. Thanks!

Comment: And i was scheduling timer in background thread. Moved this timer scheduling from background thread to main thread and its started working as i expected it to be. Thanks man.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer if your timer is using a closure...if your closure is not executing, make it async...

Answer (score 22):

Timer methods with a selector are supposed to have one parameter: The timer itself. Thus your code should really look like this: <sup>1</sup>

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.1, 
    target: self, 
    selector: #selector(self.adjustmentBestSongBpmHeartRate(_:), 
    userInfo: nil, 
    repeats: false)

@objc func adjustmentBestSongBpmHeartRate(_ timer: Timer) {
    print("frr")
 }
```

Note that if your app only runs on iOS >= 10, you can use the new method that takes a block to invoke rather than a target/selector. Much cleaner and more type-safe:

```
class func scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval interval: TimeInterval, 
    repeats: Bool, 
    block: @escaping (Timer) -> Void) -> Timer
```

That code would look like this:

```
 timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.1, 
        repeats: false) {
    timer in
    //Put the code that be called by the timer here.
    print("frr")
    }
```

Note that if your timer block/closure needs access to instance variables from your class you have to take special care with `self`. Here's a good pattern for that sort of code:

```
 timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.1, 
        repeats: false) {

    //"[weak self]" creates a "capture group" for timer
    [weak self] timer in

    //Add a guard statement to bail out of the timer code 
    //if the object has been freed.
    guard let strongSelf = self else {
        return
    }
    //Put the code that be called by the timer here.
    print(strongSelf.someProperty)
    strongSelf.someOtherProperty = someValue
    }
```

### Edit (updated 15 December)

<sup>1</sup>: I should add that the method you use in the selector has to use Objective-C dynamic dispatch. In Swift 4 and later, the individual methods you reference must be tagged with the `@objc` tag. In previous versions of Swift you could also declare the entire class that defines the selector with the `@objc` qualifier, or you could make the class that defined the selector a subclass of `NSObject` or any class that inherits from `NSOBject`. (It's quite common to define the method the timer calls inside a `UIViewController`, which is a subclass of `NSObject`, so it used to "just work".

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 3**

In my case it worked after I added to my method the **@obj prefix**

```
Class TestClass {
   private var timer: Timer?

   func start() {
        guard timer == nil else { return }
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60, target: self, selector: #selector(handleMyFunction), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }

    func stop() {
        guard timer != nil else { return }
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }


    @objc func handleMyFunction() {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point. The method the timer invokes needs to use Objective-C messaging.

Comment: And what if your `handleMyFunction` has a completion like: `completion: @escaping (String) -> (Void)`? That is throwing an error for me.

Comment: @TomSpee, you can't do that. Timers can only have no parameters, or a single parameter which is the timer itself. You might be able to pass a completion handler in as the userInfo to the timer by casting it to type `id`, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5):

Try this -

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
     self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.2, repeats: false, block: { _ in
         self.update()
     })
} else {
     self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: #selector(self.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
```

Mostly the problem must have been because of iOS version of mobile.

Answer (score 5):

Swift 5, Swift 4 Simple way only call with Dispatch Queue Async

```
DispatchQueue.main.async 
{
   self.andicator.stopAnimating()
   self.bgv.isHidden = true

   Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: false, block: { _ in

       obj.showAlert(title: "Successfully!", message: "Video save successfully to Library directory.", viewController: self)

   })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the question asked by myself.
I'm using apple watch to control my iphone app. 
I try to press a button on apple watch to present a new viewcontroller on iphone.

When I write Timer in  `override func viewDidLoad()`, Timer doesn't work. I move Timer to `override func viewWillAppear()` it works.

I think maybe there's something wrong with controlling by apple watch

---

Comment: It's related to thread's loop assignment. You can manage that by manually adding timer to processing loop (like in example: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-run-code-at-a-specific-time). In my case i used dispatch in main queue and it started to work. Weird thing

Comment: The same thing happened to me - i was invalidating the timer in viewDidDisappear, but setting it up in viewDidLoad, so the second time the view gets shown, the timer doesnt start

Answer (score 1):

I found that if you try to initialize the timer directly at the class-level, it won't work if you're targeting a selector in that same class.  When it fires, it can't find the selector.

To get around this, I only initialize the timer ***after*** the object containing the selector has been initialized.  If it's in the same class, put the initialization code in the `ViewDidLoad` or similar. Just not in the initializer.  Then it will work. No dispatch queue needed.

Also, you do *not* need to use a selector that accepts the timer as a parameter.  You can, but contrary to the answer with a ton of votes, that's not actually true, or more specifically, it works fine for me without it, just as you have it without it.

By the way, I think the reason the dispatch queue worked is because you're forcing the timer to be created after the object was initializing, confirming my above statement.

```
let timer:Timer?

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.1, target: self, selector: #selector(adjustmentBestSongBpmHeartRate), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

    timer.fire()

}

func adjustmentBestSongBpmHeartRate() {
    print("frr")
}
```

Note: This is code typed from memory, not copied from Xcode so it may not compile, but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift3**

```
var timer = Timer()

timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(self.compruebaConexion), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

my two cents.
I read about "didLoad" and when invoking it.
so we can use a delay:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var timer: Timer?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        startTimer()
    }


    final func killTimer(){
        self.timer?.invalidate()
        self.timer = nil
    }


    final private func startTimer() {

        // make it re-entrant:
        // if timer is running, kill it and start from scratch
        self.killTimer()
        let fire = Date().addingTimeInterval(1)
        let deltaT : TimeInterval = 1.0

        self.timer = Timer(fire: fire, interval: deltaT, repeats: true, block: { (t: Timer) in

            print("hello")

        })

    RunLoop.main.add(self.timer!, forMode: RunLoopMode.commonModes)

    }
```